# How can I display an HTML preview while preventing style inheritance from the rest of my site?

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea where I let users write some HTML.

They can then click a "Preview" link that triggers ajax that sends the raw HTML to a controller that uses JSoup to sanitize it (it returns the sanitized string).

I then display the sanitized HTML in a modal dialog box.

This all works wonderfully except that the modal dialog box has CSS styles cascade down from the rest of my site, and I want to display the HTML preview **without any styles**.

I've searched a lot (e.g. I found [Any way to display some heavily-styled HTML in isolation from the rest of site's styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927604/any-way-to-display-some-heavily-styled-html-in-isolation-from-the-rest-of-sites)) but wasn't able to figure out a solution.

I appreciate your help!

-Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the preview to a text file on the server then open an iframe to it with a template absent of the site's css.

I bet your problem stems from generic css selectors though. Things like

```
div p{
    background:#fff;
}
```

Or maybe not so generic, but so non specific that it is being caught by your preview.