# Light DOM style leaking into Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I am trying to create a Chrome extension with a floating widget. To do that, I have to isolate my element from the rest of the page. Shadow DOM looks like a perfect fit for that, but it isn't doing what I expected.

Here is my content script:

content.js

```
var lightDom = document.createElement('style');
lightDom.innerText = 'div { color: red }';

document.body.appendChild(lightDom);

var shadowDom = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(shadowDom);

var shadowRoot = shadowDom.attachShadow({'mode': 'open'});

shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <div>Shadow!</div>
`;
```

The div inside the shadow DOM should have black text, but it has red text instead. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

CSS selectors in Light DOM are prevented from reaching elements inside shadow DOM. But when a CSS property has the value `inherit`, which is the default value of `color`, the shadow DOM will still inherit those from the light DOM.

[From the CSS Scoping specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1)

> **3.3.2 Inheritance**
>   The top-level elements of a shadow tree inherit from their host element.
>   The elements in a distribution list inherit from the parent of the content element they are ultimately distributed to, rather than from their normal parent.

### How to prevent it from happening?

You can prevent the values of properties form being inherited by using the `initial` value.

[From the CSS Cascading and Inheritance specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/#initial-value)

> **7.3.1. Resetting a Property: the initial keyword**
>   If the cascaded value is the initial keyword, the property’s initial value becomes its specified value.

The initial value of each property is documented in the specification it is defined in. `color` is documented in the [CSS Color specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/) and its initial value is `depends on user agent`, for most user agents this will be `black`.

You can assign `initial` to each property you don't want to inherit its value. Or you can set the value of `all` to `initial`, like so:

```
.selector 
{
    all: initial;
}
```

The `all` property is defined as follows in the same spec as the initial keyword.

> **3.1. Resetting All Properties: the all property**
>   The all property is a shorthand that resets all CSS properties except direction and unicode-bidi. It only accepts the CSS-wide keywords.

"CSS-wide keywords" is defined in [CSS 3 values specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values) in section 3.1.1, but comes down to the values `initial`, `inherit` and `unset`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added `all: initial` to my `shadowDom` style to prevent this from happening. You could perhaps add that as a suggestion in your answer.

Comment: nitpicking: *`inherit` [...] is the default value of color* - I think this is not accurate. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value): "The initial value of a CSS property is its default value, as listed in its definition table.", and [definition table says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) that the initial value for `color` is browser dependant.

Comment: @HeyJude The definition table does say that. But it also says it is inherited. This means the value will be `inherit` for all elements except the root element. The color of the root element is browser dependent. This is also the behaviour I've experienced in the browsers I've tested.