# Why color applied to a body affects shadow-root

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

Here is the simple HTML I have. `h1` is inside the shadow root but it's green. Is this behavior of color inheritance from parent elements outside shadow DOM expected? I'm wondering because the element selectors can't cross shadow boundaries (`h1` styles are not applied to `h1` inside the shadow root)

```
<head>
 <style> 
    body { color: green } 
    h1 { color: red; }
 </style>
</head>

<my-element>
  #shadow-root
    <h1>text is green</h1>
</my-element>
```

Ideally I'm looking for a part of a spec that defines this behavior.

Comment: @cale_b: Not only does that question not make any mention of shadow trees, the asker here seems to understand what inheritance is and is simply asking if it applies from light elements to their shadow tree descendants. What the accepted answer to that question does tell you is that that's not what "cascading" means.

Comment: Thanks guys - totally missed the "shadow dom" tag.  Always learning on SO!

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, thanks, that's exactly my question. I've updated my example to make the question more explicit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Light DOM style leaking into Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709676/light-dom-style-leaking-into-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is expected. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping/#shadow-cascading):

> The top-level elements of a shadow tree inherit from their host element.

In your case, the shadow host, `my-element`, inherits the color from the `body` element. The `h1`, being in the shadow root of `my-element`, inherits from `my-element`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that this text no longer appears in the latest revision, which is fairly old - I'm looking around to see if it still exists in current drafts. The closest I can find is [section 3.1 of the editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#shadow-gloss), but that text is informative, not normative.

Comment: Got, thanks for the link to the spec. And as I understand, the same applies to custom properties (CSS variables)? I've tested and they seem to be able to cross shadow DOM boundaries. It should make sense that they do, because they are the mechanism instead of `>>>` selectors.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: Custom properties are indeed always inherited, so I would expect them to behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a shadowHost and shadowRoot.

**shadowRoot** is what is attached to an element to give a shadow DOM.

**shadowHost** is what that shadow root is attached to.

Aparently when you define something flat in the html page it gets attached to body element shadowroot. 
Same that say it is attached to shadowDOM of body, or with body as shadowHost.

I guess it is default behaviour as the 'default shadowRoot'. Where you are writing 'text is green' since body is supposed to be the root element for page content. While html tag describes document language. And head defines metadata content.

So green style is being correctly inherited.