# React FullCalendar not working properly inside iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension where in the content script I'm injecting the app inside an iframe and then injecting that iframe into the page whenever that content script is loaded onto the page

content.js (Content script)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Frame, { FrameContextConsumer } from "react-frame-component";

import App from "./App";

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Frame
        id="calendar-iframe"
        head={[
          <link
            type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href={chrome.runtime.getURL("/static/css/content.css")}
          ></link>,
          <link rel="preconnect" href={"https://fonts.googleapis.com"}></link>,
          <link rel="preconnect" href={"https://fonts.gstatic.com"}></link>,
        ]}
      >
        <FrameContextConsumer>
          {({ document }) => {
            return (
              <App
                iframeDocument={document}
                isExt={true}
                chrome={chrome}
                removeApp={removeApp}
              />
            );
          }}
        </FrameContextConsumer>
      </Frame>
    );
  }
}

const app = document.createElement("div");
app.id = "extension-root";

document.body.appendChild(app);

app.style.display = "none";

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, app);

function removeApp() {
  document.body.removeChild(app);
}

const toggleApp = () => {
  if (app.style.display === "none") {
    app.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    app.style.display = "none";
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === "icon_clicked") {
    toggleApp();
    sendResponse({ response: "Message received" });
  }
});
```

This is the App.js

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";

import Calendar from "./components/Calendar";

function App({ iframeDocument }) {
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Calendar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Calendar.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import "./index.css";

let eventGuid = 0;
let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, ""); // YYYY-MM-DD of today

export const INITIAL_EVENTS = [
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: "All-day event",
    start: todayStr,
  },
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: "Timed event",
    start: todayStr + "T12:00:00",
  },
];

export function createEventId() {
  return String(eventGuid++);
}

const Calendar = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    weekendsVisible: true,
    currentEvents: [],
  });

  const calendarRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Changing view");
      calendarRef?.current?.getApi()?.changeView("timeGridWeek");
      calendarRef?.current?.getApi()?.changeView("timeGridDay");
      calendarRef?.current?.getApi()?.changeView("timeGridWeek");
    }, [2000]);
  }, []);

  const handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    alert("Removing event");
    clickInfo.event.remove();
  };

  const handleEvents = (events) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      currentEvents: events,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="calendar">
      <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
        }}
        initialView={"timeGridDay"}
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        weekends={state.weekendsVisible}
        initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS} // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        eventsSet={handleEvents}
        nowIndicator={true}
        dragScroll={false}
        // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
            eventAdd={function(){}}
            eventChange={function(){}}
            eventRemove={function(){}}
            */
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
  return (
    <>
      <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
      <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
    </>
  );
}
export default Calendar;
```

But the issue I'm facing is when I try to drag onto the calendar to add events it doesn't consider the document inside the iframe but rather the document of the page into which the iframe is injected. Clicking works fine but only drag and drop are causing issues

Instead of Iframe, I tried injecting the app into a shadow root but it still causes the page CSS to override the styling inside the chrome extension.

Comment: Shadow DOM should preserve the styles if you reset those few properties that inherit across the shadow boundary, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709787).

Comment: @wOxxOm how do I prevent the styling from being applied to the code inside the library, I don't have access to that code

Comment: Add `.sel {all: initial}` to a style element inside the shadow root where `.sel` is the top element inside.