# Web Components permit external styling in or I make an error in using it?

Tags: javascript, web-component

Accordingly to sources Shadow DOM should not let external styles in.
However, either I do not understand it correctly, either I have made sth. wrong or it does.
Please have a look here

https://kiszuriwalilibori-about-me.netlify.app/

Just inspect my name. The span inside heritages( what can be verified checking/unchecking color).
The code that creates this element is

```js
customElements.define('author-name', class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super()
          .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
          .innerHTML = `
<style>
  span{
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: calc(16px + 32 * ((100vw - 320px) / 1080));
    color: #FB6542;
  }
  @media (max-width: 700px) {span {font-size:3rem;}}
  @media (max-width: 508px) {span {font-size:2rem;}}
</style>
<span>Piotr Maksymiuk</span>`;
      }
});
```

```html
<author-name></author-name>
```

So, do I not understand or the code is invalid?

Comment: Nothing wrong here; you define a style **within** the shadowDOM; it gets applied to the span

Comment: You are right - but just open DevTools and inspect span. It heritages, really. You can check the font color for example. And in my understanding it shouldn't be possible

Comment: Inherited properties cascade into shadowDOM. See (2017) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189985/shadow-dom-inheriting-parent-page-css-chrome and https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/