# Web Components with angular.js & IE11 compatibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, clone, web-component

I have angular.js application in which I would like to initialize a web component.

It works perfectly fine on other browsers but it seems that IE11 has issues with

> document.importNode

angular.js onInit function:

```
           vm.$onInit = function() {
                vm.params = $location.search();

                if(vm.params.merchantId  && vm.params.apiToken && vm.params.amount && vm.params.orderId) {
                    vm.mid = vm.params.merchantId;
                    vm.apiToken = vm.params.apiToken;
                    vm.amount = vm.params.amount;
                    vm.orderId = vm.params.orderId;

                    let template = document.querySelector('#template');
                    let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
                    let cmp = clone.querySelector('cmp-request');
                    
                    cmp.setAttribute('mid', vm.mid);

                    template.replaceWith(clone);
                    
                }
            }
```

HTML:

```
<template id="template"> 
    <cmp-request></cmp-request>
</template>
```

Is there any other way to clone web component and pass params inside without using importNode so it would work on IE11?

Comment: IE11 needs a polyfill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902255/are-web-components-actually-useable-in-ie11-and-edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 11 doesn't support `importNode` and `replaceWith`. For `importNode`, I use `children` to get `<template>`'s children to get the web component in IE 11. For `replaceWith`, I use [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith#polyfill) to support it in IE 11.

You can refer to my code sample with dummy values:

```js
function ReplaceWithPolyfill() {
  'use-strict'; // For safari, and IE > 10
  var parent = this.parentNode,
    i = arguments.length,
    currentNode;
  if (!parent) return;
  if (!i) // if there are no arguments
    parent.removeChild(this);
  while (i--) { // i-- decrements i and returns the value of i before the decrement
    currentNode = arguments[i];
    if (typeof currentNode !== 'object') {
      currentNode = this.ownerDocument.createTextNode(currentNode);
    } else if (currentNode.parentNode) {
      currentNode.parentNode.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
    // the value of "i" below is after the decrement
    if (!i) // if currentNode is the first argument (currentNode === arguments[0])
      parent.replaceChild(currentNode, this);
    else // if currentNode isn't the first
      parent.insertBefore(currentNode, this.nextSibling);
  }
}
if (!Element.prototype.replaceWith)
  Element.prototype.replaceWith = ReplaceWithPolyfill;
if (!CharacterData.prototype.replaceWith)
  CharacterData.prototype.replaceWith = ReplaceWithPolyfill;
if (!DocumentType.prototype.replaceWith)
  DocumentType.prototype.replaceWith = ReplaceWithPolyfill;


var template = document.querySelector('#template');
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1) { //IE11
  var clone = template.children[0];
  clone.setAttribute('mid', 'test');
} else {
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  var cmp = clone.querySelector('cmp-request');
  cmp.setAttribute('mid', 'test');
}
template.replaceWith(clone);
```

```html
<template id="template">
   <cmp-request></cmp-request>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped!